# Grails - Combine multiple gsp head tag content into complete page

Tags: grails, layout, head

Trying to build a page from several gsp pages that each have content that needs to be in the head section of the final document. I can't get style or script from g:include into the final head tag.

The use model is for the controller to render a page using `<meta name="layout" content="page">` and the page.gsp layout will call g:include with model data for header, footer, and menu. Each has some javascript or style that needs to end up in the final head section.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this preserving localized head content to each included gsp page?

**Update:**

Using `<g:applyLayout>` tag with a layout that contains only `<g:layoutBody/>` or `<g:layoutHead/>` solves the issue. However, to get the head and body in the correct spot I am calling `<g:include>` twice, once with layoutHead and a second time with layoutBody. Using a layout with both layoutHead and layoutBody does not result in the correct merge.